# Linear regression (Plotting a regression line)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to plot a regression line for my assignment as shown below.

```
# Basic Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sb.set()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#Structure of data that I am working with

hsedata = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

salePrice = pd.DataFrame(hsedata['SalePrice'])
grLivArea = pd.DataFrame(hsedata['GrLivArea'])

SPtrain, SPtest, LAtrain, LAtest = train_test_split(salePrice, grLivArea, test_size = 0.2)
```

[SPtrain Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5hab.png)

[LAtrain Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDtSn.png)

```
#Linear Regression
linreg = LinearRegression()

linreg.fit(LAtrain, SPtrain)
print('Intercept: ', linreg.intercept_)
print('Gradient: ', linreg.coef_)
```

Intercept:  [22485.24894138]
Gradient:  [[103.92233101]]

```
salePricePredict = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(LAtrain))
print(salePricePredict.shape)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.scatter(LAtrain, SPtrain)
plt.scatter(LAtrain, salePricePredict, color = 'r')
plt.show()
```

[Scatterplot regression line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqcxs.png)

Up to this point, I managed to print out the regression line with plt.scatter() with no issue as shown above. However, I want to print out a straight line instead with the following code below:

```
salePricePredict = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(LAtrain))
f = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.scatter(LAtrain, SPtrain)
plt.plot(LAtrain, salePricePredict, color = 'r')
plt.show()
```

But this produces error type:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 f = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
      3 plt.scatter(LAtrain, SPtrain)
----> 4 plt.plot(LAtrain, salePricePredict, color = 'r')
      5 plt.show()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:487, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    484         kw[prop_name] = val
    486 if len(xy) == 2:
--> 487     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
    488     y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:1327, in _check_1d(x)
   1321 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
   1322     warnings.filterwarnings(
   1323         "always",
   1324         category=Warning,
   1325         message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
-> 1327     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328     # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329     # cast to a numpy array.
   1330     if len(w) > 0:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3628, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3623         raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624     except TypeError:
   3625         # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626         #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627         #  the TypeError.
-> 3628         self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3629         raise
   3631 # GH#42269

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5637, in Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5633 def _check_indexing_error(self, key):
   5634     if not is_scalar(key):
   5635         # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5636         # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5637         raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

However if I add in .squeeze() to both parameters for .plot as shown below, it works as intended:

```
salePricePredict = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(LAtrain))
f = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.scatter(LAtrain, SPtrain)
plt.plot(LAtrain.squeeze(), salePricePredict.squeeze(), color = 'r')
plt.show()
```

[With .squeeze() added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7v3.png)

I was wondering why is this the case and what does .squeeze() do to my input datatype? I've tried reading some documentation and explanation as to what it does but I got nowhere with it.

I've also tried comparing the datatypes of what I was working with by using .shape, but .squeeze() does not seem to change anything. Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What numpy squeeze does is removing the dimensions of size 1 from your array.
The output of your prediction is a two dimensional array, and matplotlib .plot() method can't plot a vector against a two dimensional array.

Try doing the following:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(X.shape)
print(X.squeeze().shape)
```

Check how X has only one dimension after using .squeeze(); it has become a vector.

---

You can check the same by reading the code below:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

plt.plot(a.squeeze(), b) # This works

plt.plot(a,b) # This throws a ValueError
```